# Uploading of image to WordPress through Python's requests

Tags: wordpress, python-3.x, python-requests

In order to validate the installation of WordPress instances, we are writing Python unit tests. One of the test should perform the following action: upload an image to WordPress.

In order to do that, I am using the Requests library.

When I inspect the form within /wp-admin/media-new.php page through Firebug (form information, I get the following information):
Form 
Id: file-form
Name
Method: post
Action: http://localhost:8000/wp-admin/media-new.php

Elements 
id: plupload-browse-button 
type: button 
value: Select Files

id:async-upload 
name: async-upload 
type: file 
label: Upload

id:html-upload 
name: html-upload 
type: submit 
value: Upload

id: post_id 
name: post_id 
type: hidden 
value: 0

id: _wpnonce 
name: _wpnonce 
type: hidden 
value: c0fc3b80bb

id: file-form 
name: _wp_http_referer 
type: hidden 
value: /wp-admin/media-new.php

I believe that the _wpnonce is a unique value generated for each session. Therefore, before trying to upload the file, I get the media-new.php page and grab the _wpnonce in the form (hence the variable in my code).

My code is the following:

```
    with open('1.jpg', 'rb') as f:
        upload_data = {'post_id': '0',
                       '_wp_http_referer': '/wp-admin/media-new.php',
                       '_wpnonce': wp_nonce,
                       'action': 'upload_attachement',
                       'name': '1.jpg',
                       'async-upload': f,
                       'html-upload': 'Upload'}
        upload_result = session.post('http://localhost:8000/wp-admin/media-new.php', upload_data)
```

The code runs fine and the upload_result.status_code equals 200.

However, the image never shows up in the media gallery of WordPress.

I believe this a simple error, but I can't figure out what I'm missing.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I think this [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/240487/media-files-exist-in-upload-folder-but-not-showing-up) will help you. Check uploads folder permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to post files you should use the `files` parameter. Also the `'_wpnonce'` value is not enough to get authenticated, you need to have cookies.

```
url = 'http://localhost:8000/wp-admin/media-new.php'
data = {
    'post_id': '0',
    '_wp_http_referer': '/wp-admin/media-new.php',
    '_wpnonce': wp_nonce,
    'action': 'upload_attachement',
    'html-upload': 'Upload'
}
files = {'async-upload':('1.jpg', open('1.jpg', 'rb'))}
headers = {'Cookie': my_cookies}
upload_result = session.post(url, data=data, files=files, headers=headers)
```

I'm assuming that you have acquired valid cookies from your browser. If you want to get authenticated with `requests` check my answer to this post: [login-wordpress-with-requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43562550/login-wordpress-with-requests-python3/43563859#43563859)

Comment: Thanks, it did work. However, I did not need the cookies. I believe I did not need them since I was still in the same session.

Comment: Yes, if you have an authenticated session you don't need to worry about cookies.