# How to disable my reCaptcha v3 for Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, recaptcha-v3

I'm trying to test my web app and for that, I need to bypass my reCaptcha v3, it is a button with no game for verification, it is hidden.

In reCaptcha v2 you were able to disable it through your site key and secret key, how is it done with the v3?

Thanks!

Comment: This will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55501524/how-does-recaptcha-3-know-im-using-selenium-chromedriver